# Double integral. Is this the correct area of integration?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

I have to compute a double integral with respect to an area $U$ defined as follows:
$$U=\{(u_1,u_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2; u_2 - u_1 \leq a\}\tag{1}$$
That is:
$$\displaystyle{\int\int_U}du_1du_2\tag{2}$$

---

I would say that bounds of integration are the following:
$$\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{u_2-a}^{+\infty}}du_1du_2\tag{2. bis}$$

---

---

Is there something wrong? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see anything wrong in your integral bounds

The other way to integrate is the following

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Bigg[\int_{-\infty}^{u_1+a}du_2\Bigg]du_1$$

Comment: Very good to know, thank you a lot. If I perform the following change of variable $$u_1=x\text{ and } u_2-u_1=y$$ the same integral becomes:
$$\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{a}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}}$$
since now $U=\{(x,y); y\leq a\}$ (while $x$ could range from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, not subject to any condition). Could you please confirm if such a reasoning is correct? @tommik

Comment: @Strictly_increasing : that's ok